# sequence $x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \sin x_{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

There is a sequence which satisfies
$$x_{1} = a$$
$$x_{n+1} = x_{n} + \sin x_{n}$$
where a = 1 . 
Why does $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_{n} = \pi$$ hold ??

(the first version of question was with 2 misprints!!)

Comment: It doesn't. Take $a=0$.

Comment: take $a=0$, the limit is thus $0$

Comment: Also, what have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: If $x_n \to x$, we have $x = x+ \sin x$ by continity, hence $\sin x = 0$, so $x\in \pi\mathbb Z$.

Comment: There's something wrong with your definition - $\frac\pi2$ isn't a fixed point of your recurrence.  That is, if $|x_n-\frac\pi2|\lt\epsilon$ for some small $\epsilon$, $\sin x_n\approx 1$ so $|x_{n+1}-\frac\pi2|\gt\frac12$.  Are you sure you don't want $\cos$ there, for instance?

Comment: Note that if $x_n$ is close to $\pi/2$, her kid is far away from that.

Comment: the answers have explained that it will converge to an integer multiple of pi (for all a) so given that a=1, it converges to a nearby multiple (which is pi, as you said)

Comment: @KayneWest If your question has already three(!) answers, you should consider accepting one and asking the corrected question as a new one, leaving this one here in the old state.

Comment: See here ... for example: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2304/question-edited-to-change-meaning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$ then $f$ is strictly increasing on $[0,\pi)$ and $f((0,\pi))\subset(0,\pi)$, so if $x_1=a\in(0,\pi)$ then $x_n\in(0,\pi)$. Moreover, it is clear that $f(x)>x$ for $x\in(0,\pi)$. That is
$$\forall\,x\in(0,\pi),\qquad 0<x<f(x)<\pi$$
So, if $x_1=a\in(0,\pi)$ then by an easy induction we get
$$\forall\,n\geq1,\qquad 0<x_n<x_{n+1}<\pi$$
This proves that $(x_n)_{n\geq1}$ is bounded and increasing. So, it must convege to some
limit $\ell\in(0,\pi]$ with $f(\ell)=\ell$. this implies that $\ell=\pi$ and we are done.

**Remark.** The convergence of this sequence is remarkably fast. Indeed, if $e_n=\pi-x_n$ then
$$0\leq e_{n+1}=e_n-\sin e_n\leq \frac{e_n^3}{6}$$
So the rate of convergence is cubic. For instance, when $x_1=1$ we have $e_6=5.6 \times 10^{-17}$, while for $x_1=3$ we have $e_4<10^{-16}$.
$$
0<\pi-\left(
3+\sin 3+\sin (3+\sin  3)+\sin (3+\sin  3+\sin (3+\sin  3))\right)<10^{-16}.$$

Comment: Using the same argument with decreasing instead of increasing, we see that $x_n\to\pi $ for all $a\in(0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, Generally, for $a\in(2k\pi,2(k+1)\pi)$ the sequence converges to $(2k+1)\pi$

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that the limit exists, let $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x$.  Then:

$$\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n+\sin(x_n)\right) \implies x=x+\sin(x)$$

Thus:
$$0=\sin(x) \implies x = k\pi, \quad k\in\Bbb{Z}$$

Thus, your stated equality does not hold.

Comment: Ugh.  I wasn't watching the comments above while typing this...

Comment: the first version was definitely wrong , for example a = 0 )))) i have updated question

Comment: Kanye, please read this. No matter your initial a, Anorton's answer holds and explains why it converges.

Comment: @oliveeuler No, it does not, it explaines that *if it converges*, then to a multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: but it is easy to show that if a = 1 the sequence converges. so thanks for everyone  answered

Comment: @oliveeuler: Martini is correct - my answer *assumes* the sequence converges.  It certainly does not prove that it does.

Comment: @martini You're right. I meant that changing $a$ doesn't refute any of the answers here (if it is convergent).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't necessarily hold for all a. For example

$$x_{1} = {n\pi} \implies x_{n} = x_{1} \forall n$$

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean $x_{n+1}=x_n+\cos x_n$?

We know $\sin y<y$ when $0<y<\pi/2$, so substitute $x=\pi/2-y$ and get $\cos x< \pi/2-x$ when $0<x<\pi/2$.

So adding $\cos x_n$ will not quite reach $\pi/2$.

On the other hand, $\sin y$ and $y$ get very close when $x$ is small, so adding this term gets very close to $\pi/2$.